# sell32.dll resign digital signature

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, sign, shell32.dll

I am trying to edit shell32.dll icons but when I replace it with the original one my windows did not boot the I found that the shell32.dll can't be edited unless you remove the digital sign by signtool from the windows SDK and I did this easily with this command

```
signtool remove /s [path]/shell32.dll
```

but when I try to resign the dll file with this command

```
signtool sign /a [path]/shell32.dll
```

I got this error

> SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

Answer (score 0):

1. The sign command requires you to provide a certificate with a private key for signing.
2. Windows requires all system files to be signed with microsoft signatures. Therefore your system crashes.
3. Signing files requires a private key that is kept secret.

Conclusion: You cannot edit shell32.dll without causing a system crash.

P.S .:
There is a possibility that system files can be signed with a driver signature, but this is not verified information.
https://support.globalsign.com/code-signing/code-signing-windows-7-8-and-10